# How to use „LOAD CSV FROM“ command with Authorization and bearer token in Neo4j?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, etl

## Initial situation

- Standalone Neo4j Server (Version 3.5.13, Enterprise edition), APOC 3.5.0.6
- Requirement

  - import CSV files from a remote server via URI into a graph daily
  - import is automatically executed code based by calling a cypher statement `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 LOAD CSV […]`
- Data volume: Higher double-digit million number of rows per CSV file
- I am familiar with the principle of importing CSV files and creating corresponding graphs.

## To be solved challenge

- How can I convince the `LOAD CSV FROM` command to use an Authorization with bearer token, so it can access the resource?

## Approach to the problem / preliminary result

- For GraphQL and APOC I found an appropriate interface, but I do not succeed in transferring it to the `LOAD CSV FROM` command:

  - `CALL graphql.introspect(„<URI>“, {Authorization: "bearer <bearer string>“})`
  - `CALL apoc.load.jsonParams(„<URI>“, {Authorization: "Bearer <bearer string>"}, null) YIELD value`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your Neo4j settings?

```
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

This setting must exist and be enabled to allow for URL imports.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @yyyguy. From the [Neo4j documentation] (https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#query-load-csv-introduction) I understood „This setting determines if Cypher will allow the use of `file:///` URLs when loading data using `LOAD CSV`. Such URLs identify files on the filesystem of the database server.“.

Comment: Since Neo4j runs on a separate server, the CSV file to be imported must be obtained from another server using the HTTP protocol. To obtain the CSV file, the `LOAD CSV` command must authenticate itself with a bearer token, which it sends with the HTTP request. How do I give the `LOAD CSV` command the Bearer Token and thus initiate the successful access to the CSV resource?